# How to get VS or Xcode warning with something like "x = x++"?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, xcode4.3, undefined-behavior, sequence-points

In the spirit of undefined behavior associated with sequence points such as [“x = ++x” is it really undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619323/x-x-is-it-really-undefined), how does one get the compiler to complain about such code?

Specifically, I am using Visual Studio 2010 and Xcode 4.3.1, the latter for an OSX app, and neither warned me about this. I even cranked up the warnings on VS2010 to "all", and it happily compiled this. (For the record, VS2010's version added 1 to the variable where Xcode's version kept the variable unchanged.)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, Visual Studio does not detect such situations. And I'm personally not convinced that there's much point in doing that. I'd say that a warning for a fairly obvious case like that would have mostly educational value, but not much practical value. In general case the issue in question takes place in situations like `*p = ++*q` when `p` and `q` happen to point to the same object. Needless to say, they are not detectable by the compiler.

Comment: Well, I am dealing with legacy code that had exactly `x = x++;`. It took a while to track down the symptom I was seeing to this particular line of code. Having a warning would have absolutely been of practical use.

Comment: Actually, it seems gcc does detect this (via -Wsequence-point) but not clang (which is what I'm using on OSX) - http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=4579

Comment: @Jim Buck: Yes, GCC is known to detect this. I'm not aware of any other compiler that does.

Comment: Yeah, that's a bummer. The best I could do to try to find this very specific case is a "file search" using a regexp.